# JSDoc: where to put overloaded function description

Tags: javascript, overloading, jsdoc

Given the following overloaded function documented with JSDoc, where can I put the description of said function?

```js
/**
 * @overload
 * @param {string} arg0
 * @return {void}
 *//**
 * @overload
 * @param {number} arg0
 * @param {number} arg1
 * @return {void}
 *//**
 * @param {string | number} arg0
 * @param {number} [arg1]
 */
function foo(arg0, arg1) {
  // ...
}
```

In a non-overloaded function it would be like this:

```js
/**
 * Description of the function goes here
 *
 * @param {string | number} arg0
 * @param {number} [arg1]
 */
function foo(arg0, arg1) {
    // ...
}
```

But doing the same with the overloaded function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [JSDoc documentation](https://jsdoc.app/), no `@overload` keyword exists.

### JS

It should be like your example except for the `@overload` keyword in JS, but doc tools and IDEs may not support it yet.

```js
/**
 * @param {string} arg0
 * @return {void}
 *//**
 * @param {number} arg0
 * @param {number} arg1
 * @return {void}
 *//**
 * @param {string | number} arg0
 * @param {number} [arg1]
 */
function foo(arg0, arg1) {
  // ...
}
```

### TS

In TypeScript, however, it is more intuitive, and tools like TypeDoc already support it.

```
/**
 * @param arg0 is a parameter which is a number.
 * @param arg1 is a parameter which is a number.
 * @returns a number.
 */
function foo(arg0: number, arg1: number): number;

/**
 * @param arg0 is a parameter which is a string.
 * @param arg1 is a parameter which is a number.
 * @returns a string.
 */
function foo(arg0: string, arg1: number): string;

/**
 * @param arg0 is a parameter which is a number or string.
 * @param arg1 is a parameter which is a number.
 * @returns a number or a string.
 */
function foo(arg0: number | string, arg1?: number): number | string {
  return typeof arg0 === "string" ? "A" : 0;
}
```

EDIT: Thanks, Fede G. You reminded me that the keyword was added to the TypeScript as of version 5 as documented [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#overload-support-in-jsdoc). However, `@overload` is not part of the official JSDoc and TypeScript specific, but a great addition, which enables our code and documents more flexible. I copy/pasted the code below from the official TypeScript announcement:

```
/**
 * @overload
 * @param {string} value
 * @return {void}
 */

/**
 * @overload
 * @param {number} value
 * @param {number} [maximumFractionDigits]
 * @return {void}
 */

/**
 * @param {string | number} value
 * @param {number} [maximumFractionDigits]
 */
function printValue(value, maximumFractionDigits) {
    if (typeof value === "number") {
        const formatter = Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
            maximumFractionDigits,
        });
        value = formatter.format(value);
    }

    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Seems like it was implemented in TypeScript: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#overload-support-in-jsdoc

Comment: It seems it was added to TypeScript v5. However, it is still not available on the official JSDoc. By the way, it was working in TypeScript v3 and v4, as in the example above, without the keyword. The addition of the keyword lets us write more flexible code, which is great.